# Unexpected behaviour while iterating directories in python

Tags: python, iteration

I'm making an inventory in a spreadsheet of all the files in a big library. The idea is to write the **paths** to one column, the **parent directory** of the file to a second colum, and the **filenames** to a third column.

I need it to write the parent directory to the corresponding cell for each file and that means writing that folder's name as many times as there are files inside it.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import openpyxl

def crearlista (*arg, **kw):
    inventario = openpyxl.Workbook(encoding = "Utf-8")
    sheet = inventario.active
    i = 1
    e = ""
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk("//media//rayeus/Datos/Mis Documentos/Nueva carpeta/", topdown=False):

        for name in subdirs:
            e = os.path.join (name)


        for name in files:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value = name
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value = dirpath
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = e
        i = i + 1
```

This works almost perfectly: it iterates through every file in the folder and writes its name and its dirpath in the desired locations. The problem is that it starts iterating through the files in the first folder without setting the **e** variable. 
So for the first 3 rows in the second column I get 3 blank cells, and after that it fills the following cells with the name of the folders in order (each one of those names repeated as many times as the number of files in the next folder instead of the number of files on the correspondent folder).

**Essentially my problem is that it iterates through the files in the first folder before setting the `e` variable to the corresponding folder name.**

**In other words, the writing of the files' name and dirpath is going one step further than the writing of the parent directory so it messes the second column completely.**

Example of the output file:

```
Nueva carpeta/-assorted-/The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587) "          "    cover.jpg
Nueva carpeta/-assorted-/The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587) "          "    metadata.opf
Nueva carpeta/-assorted-/The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587) "          "    The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lecture - -assorted-.pdf
Nueva carpeta/100 Recetas De Cocina Espanola/http___www.recetas.net_admin_libros (5831) The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587)  cover.jpg
Nueva carpeta/100 Recetas De Cocina Espanola/http___www.recetas.net_admin_libros (5831) The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587)  http___www.recetas.net_admin_li - 100 Recetas De Cocina Espanola.pdf
Nueva carpeta/100 Recetas De Cocina Espanola/http___www.recetas.net_admin_libros (5831) The.Galactic.Black.Hole.Lectures.on (3587)  metadata.opf
```

Comment: The `p = os.path.join(dirpath)` line could be completely removed. BTW, what do you exactly want to put to the `e` variable? For me it isn't clear from your code and question.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in what you do and ask here. `os.path.join` makes only sense with 2 or more arguments, so your `e` is always just the last of `subdirs`, either for the current loop, or even from the one before. Similarily, `p` is just always `dirpath`. Can you tell us what you want as an result, preferrably by producing a hand-made CSV example?

Comment: Yes, there is some residual code since i´ve been trying to do it for some time now and forgot to erase some superflous thing, i just edited it for beter comprension, and reformuled the answey. i hope its more clear now

Comment: @deets Thats precisely what i want. For each folder name e has to take that name as its value so i can use it on the second iteration to write it as many times as necesary

Comment: For me it is still not clear what is supposed to go to `e`. Why don't you write an example?

Comment: So all you need is a `sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value  = os.path.dirname(dirpath)` to get the parent directory? If not, then please show an example of a directory structure & what you want in your cells.

Comment: No, wait, i though thats what i needed because i tried it and at first it gave what i needed, but i tried it again and that returns the 2 level parent directory. If the file is in a/b/c/x.txt it returns a full path being it a/b and i just really want it to return c

Comment: **Don't pass `basename` a path ending in separator. Your mistake is the trailing slash in `os.walk("../Nueva carpeta/")`** Anyway, `pathlib` module is strongly preferred to `os.path` these days.

Comment: If you had debugged your issue down to the minimal example (MCVE), your question was simply *"Calling `os.path.basename()` on a path ending in separator doesn't work right."* So omit the trailing separator. Also stop using `os.path`, use `pathlib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is 'a/b/c/x.txt', `dirpath` is 'a/b/c' and 'x.txt' should be in `files`. `basename(dirpath)` will return 'c'.

**If `dirpath` ends with a slash like 'a/b/c/', `basename(dirpath)` will return '', an empty string.** In that case, `basename(dirname('a/b/c/'))` will return 'c'.

```
from os.path import basename, dirname
import openpyxl

def crearlista (*arg, **kw):
    inventario = openpyxl.Workbook(encoding = "Utf-8")
    sheet = inventario.active
    i = 1

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk("//media//rayeus/Datos/Mis Documentos/Nueva carpeta/", topdown=False):    
        file_dir = basename(dirpath) or dirname(basename(dirpath))
        for name in files:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value = dirpath
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = file_dir
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value = name
            i += 1
```

Comment: This sort of hides the prescriptive advice **Don't pass `basename` a path ending in separator. Your mistake is the trailing slash in `os.walk("../Nueva carpeta/")`**. Anyway, `pathlib` module is strongly preferred to `os.path` these days.